# Why would loading nodes by UUID not work in a drush command?

Tags: entities, drush

I have a simple bit of test code to load nodes by UUID:

```
$uuids = ['5e331255-adf6-423e-a355-dc02c621ffcd'];
$nids = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')
  ->getQuery()
  ->condition('uuid', $uuids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
```

When I execute this code in `hook_page_attachments_alter()`, or anywhere else in a rendered page build, `$nids` is populated as expected with the correct node ID.

When I execute exactly the same code, verbatim, in a drush command, `$nids` is empty.

Loading the node by ID works fine in both contexts:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load(12345);
```

This happens with the same code/database in multiple environments (Lando, ACSF, standard LAMP), and I've confirmed that drush is connecting to the correct database everywhere.

Are there any obvious properties of the node or storage system, or configuration of drush, which could be responsible for this?

Content moderation, revisions, and translations are all enabled for the node's content type, in case it matters.

Comment: Does it help to disable the query access check? `->accessCheck(FALSE)`

Comment: If I had a penny for every time I've forgotten that...thank you hugely @4uk4, that is indeed the problem and now I know which module I need to patch and file a bug report to. If you put an answer in I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the query access check

```
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
```

or use this service

```
$node = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('node', $uuid);
```